# android html links

Tags: java, android

Using this code `map.put(TAG_LINK, "" + Html.fromHtml(link));` i am able to parse json hyperlinks into my view. But the problem is it will only show me the word and i`m not able to click on it. For example if i have

```
<a href="http://something"> CLICK </a>
```

, i can only see CLICK but i cant click it. I understand there is more to html.fromhtml to work, setMovementMethod. BUt i don't know how to use it with map.put. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should tell the TextView to make it clickable links

```
textView.setAutoLinkMask( Linkify.ALL );
```

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setAutoLinkMask(int)

Comment: yes but i need to add this with map.put and that i don`t know how

Comment: Why? And if you need to, then you should create a "wrapper" object, which hold's the text, and the property you want it to have. Then put this "wrapper" object into the map.